# Update rule with gradient of loss AND loss itself multiplied

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, gradient-descent, stochastic-gradient-descent

I was reading a [paper about Neural Holography (page 5, equation 4)](http://www.computationalimaging.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/NeuralHolography_SIGAsia2020.pdf), where authors used simple stochastic gradient descent as optimizing method. There I have encountered following update rule:
[image]

, where *alpha* is a learning rate, *L* is a loss function. So basically they update parameter *phi* using **both** gradient of loss and loss itself. I have never encountered such an update rule. What is this update rule? They never specified, why they did it this way.

Comment: it's just an odd notation. They are doing regular gradient descent